# Adding a another level of columns for a pandas data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I have a data frame that consists of 60 columns; and for the sake of illustration I will be showing an example data frame that looks like what I have but much shorter. the example data frame  looks like this:

```
       0         1     ...     0         1     ...
0 -0.611064 -0.032586  ... -0.102049  1.582183 ...
```

what I want is to add another level of columns on top of the existing columns so it becomes something like this:

```
           A                       B
      0         1     ...     0         1      ... 
0 -0.611064 -0.032586 ...  -0.102049  1.582183 ...
```

I have tried the following:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'], df.columns])
```

but I got an error that says

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 60 elements, new values have 120 elements
```

after some search I knew that error was due to that the number of columns that I am trying to assign is larger than the existing columns but still I haven't been able so solve this problem.

I also tried several method like `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` and `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays` with other error produced.

**edit:**
here is an reproducible example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,4), columns=[0,1,0,1])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'], df.columns])
print(df)
```

can any one point to a solution to this problem?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so we can recreate your example.

Comment: Hi @Paul, I edited the post, please have a look. thanks!

Comment: I believe @AlexK already provided you with a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you just need to create a repeating sequence of `A`'s and `B`'s, with the length of the sequence equal to the number of your current columns. You can do it using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [np.repeat(['A','B'], df.shape[1] // 2), df.columns]
)
```

The first array above will look like `['A','A','B','B',...]`.

---

**Update**:

In response to your follow-up question in the comments below, if you have an odd number of columns, you can utilize [`np.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) to create a full array of alternating `A`'s and `B`'s (i.e. `['A','A','B','B','A','A',...]`) with the length equal to the number of columns in your dataframe. Then, you can pass that array to `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays()`:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [np.resize(np.repeat(['A','B'], 2), df.shape[1]), df.columns]
)
```

Comment: Thank you @AlexK for your answer, I just have another question! 
How to add this level if the number of columns was odd? I know it will rias an error, I wondering if there is workaround that ?

Comment: @AdelMoustafa Do you mean there would be for example 61 columns, or do you mean there would be three values, like A, B and C? And what result would you need? Can you provide an example? You can edit your question and include it there.

Comment: I mean the number of columns as you said, I imagine I would go about this with a simple if-else to check the number of columns ( if it's even proceed as your solution and if not add a dummy column to make the number of columns even and proceed with your solution). I wondering if there is a better way to deal with this?
thanks

Comment: @AdelMoustafa, please see the update above in response to your follow-up question.